# iOS: Add an invisible row to a UICollectionView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have the following situation:

I am developing a game where players can be part of a group, and it has a view listing all the groups the player has currently joined. By design, the list of groups falls under a button panel located at the bottom of the screen.

**I have uploaded a picture explaining the situation
[right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s4sj.png), as i'm not allowed to upload images yet.**

The feed of my collection view is a array, containing all the groups

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("GroupCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GroupCell
        var list = groupArray

        cell.setButtonTitle(list[indexPath.row].groupName)

        // Give the button a tag so it can be identified later, in prepareForSegue
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "toGroupPage:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return cell;
}
```

**So my Question is:**

Is there a way to add a bottom row to my Collection View so that the 'real' buttons will not fall behind my panel and become unclickable? I've tried adding three empty entries to my groupArray, but to no avail as it messed up the whole collection view. 
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the contentInset property on the collection view. Set the bottom value to whatever spacing you need to use.